# How to detect a touch on a dynamically created tablelayout?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-tablelayout

I created a dynamically programmed tablelayout on android for my wordsearch app. This is the code:

```
    public void createGrid(char[][] input) {
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "kg.ttf");


    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        LinearLayout rowLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        rowLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        rowLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        final TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        for (int j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
            final TextView text = new TextView(this);
            Character temp = input[i][j];
            text.setTag(i);
            text.setText(temp.toString());
            text.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
            text.setTag(i);
            text.setTextSize(txtSize);
            text.setTypeface(font);
            text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            row.addView(text);
        }
        table.addView(row);



        table.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        startX = motionEvent.getX();
                        startY = motionEvent.getY();
                        Log.e("DOWN", "DOWN");
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        endX = motionEvent.getX();
                        endY = motionEvent.getY();
                        Log.e("MOVE", "MOVE" + " " + view.getTag());
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        endX = motionEvent.getX();
                        endY = motionEvent.getY();
                        Log.e("UP","UP " + view.getTag());
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
  }
```

As you can see, I put a touch event on the table. But the output returns this:

> `E/DOWN: DOWN
>   E/MOVE: MOVE null
>   E/MOVE: MOVE null
>   E/MOVE: MOVE null
>   E/UP: UP null`

I tried putting `table.setTag(1)` on my TableLayout and I see that what the touch really returns is the tag of the TableLayout and not the tag of the dynamically created TextViews.

Is there any way to detect those textviews?

Any help is really much appreciated.

And if there's a duplicate question of this, please let me know.

Comments, answers, and suggestions are really much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Because i want to detect those `textViews` on each cell of the `tableLayout` and get the values inside the selected textViews to create a string. And if that string will be equal to one of the values inside the `txt` file, a line will be drawn on the `tablelayout`.

**EDIT:**

I tried modifying the `onTouch()` method of my table:

It is like this:

```
   table.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            for (int i = 0; i < table.getChildCount(); i++) {

                TextView v = (TextView)row.getChildAt(i);
                String tv = v.getText().toString();
                switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        startX = motionEvent.getX();
                        startY = motionEvent.getY();
                        Log.e("DOWN", "DOWN");
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        endX = motionEvent.getX();
                        endY = motionEvent.getY();
                        Log.e("MOVE", "MOVE " + tv);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        endX = motionEvent.getX();
                        endY = motionEvent.getY();
                        Log.e("UP", "UP " + tv + table.getChildCount());
                        break;
                }
            }return true;
        }
    });
```

But it only detects the last row of my `TableLayout`.

**What I want the `onTouch()` method to do is to detect the `TextViews` inside the row and change the text color and background color of the `TextViews` that were touched/swiped.**

Comment: Perhaps you want to add the setontouchlistener outside the forloop?

Comment: @TotumusMaximus could you explain it in a code?

Comment: Right now you are creating touchlisteners on the table for every row that table has. You should move one of the }'s at the end of your code to before the table.setontouchlistener

Comment: @TotumusMaximus I tried it now but it doesn't work. It now returns

`E/DOWN: DOWN
E/MOVE: MOVE 1
E/MOVE: MOVE 1
E/MOVE: MOVE 1
E/MOVE: MOVE 1
E/MOVE: MOVE 1
E/MOVE: MOVE 1
E/MOVE: MOVE 1
E/MOVE: MOVE 1
E/MOVE: MOVE 1
E/MOVE: MOVE 1
E/MOVE: MOVE 1
E/MOVE: MOVE 1
E/MOVE: MOVE 1
E/MOVE: MOVE 1
E/MOVE: MOVE 1
E/MOVE: MOVE 1
E/MOVE: MOVE 1
E/MOVE: MOVE 1
E/MOVE: MOVE 1
E/MOVE: MOVE 1
E/MOVE: MOVE 1
E/MOVE: MOVE 1
E/MOVE: MOVE 1
E/MOVE: MOVE 1
E/UP: UP 1`

Comment: Nice, That is improvement. It means the problem was with the touchlistener as I expected. The next thing I want you to try is changing the tag of those views you try to get. Add a tag to the table and row. Make sure they are unique for you. Then change the tags for each cell to I*100 + j. Then add a bit of extra log to the onTouch events. I want you to log not only the tag but also a string representation of the view object. Add those results to an edit in your question for readability.

Comment: @TotumusMaximus I can't get what you mean by "change the tags for each cell to l*100 + j". Do you mean like this: `textView.setTag(i*100+j)`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This way you can easily identify each cell within your table. Your latest edit is a step in the wrong direction. Did you place the table.setOnTouchListener OUTSIDE of the loops as I meant with an earlier comment. And did you make a more clear log within the OnTouch override so we know the coordinate and the class of the view that received the event?